# Why does this menu css not work with internet explorer 8, but works with chrome,firefox,etc?

Tags: css, menu

Please take a look at my menu code on my site. You can view the source and css file on this site: http://a4um.com/menu.php

Comment: well there are going to be many such issues, better you should switch to some javascript api like Jquery. Because there are a lot of browser dependent points which we have to take care.

Comment: just right click the screen and click view page source.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is get rid of your non-unique IDs. At my company, we use class="parent" for top level li elements, class="children" for second level ul elements, and class="child" for second level li elements. The only element that you might want to assign an id to is the top level ul.

Answer (score 0):

some of element is not supported by ie so you can include js for ie

for reference https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css"><!-- your css without change -->

<!-- add this for ie support-->


    <!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->



</head>
<body>
    <div id="big_wrapper">
        <header id="top_header">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="moreButton"><a href="#" class="hide">Menu </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li id="second"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                            <br>
                            <li id="second"><a href="#">Mail</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This actually worked for me. The bottom of the webpage now says there are errors on the page, but as long as it's displaying the site properly I'm satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

you have used html 5 tags i.e; nav,header which are not valid in ie lower versions so follow the below code it may help you.

```
 <div id="big_wrapper">
            <div id="top_header">
    <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                    </li>
                    <li id="moreButton"><a href ="#" class = "hide">
                        Menu
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id = "second"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                        <br>

                                    <li id = "second"><a href="#">Mail</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>


*{
     margin: 0px;
     padding:0px;
}

.hide{
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.hide:link{
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.hide:visited{
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.hide:hover{
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.hide:active{
    font: bold 23px Tahoma;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}


header,section,footer,aside,nav,article,hgroup{
    display:block;
}
body{
    width:100%;
    height:110%;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
}
#big_wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom:0; left:0;

    background:#F0F0F0;

    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1
}
#top_header{
    background: #252525;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-left:1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    color: white;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;left:0;
}
#logoThing{
    width:100px;
    font: bold 25px Tahoma;
    padding-left:300px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
#otherTopStuff{
    width:120px;
    font: bold 25px Tahoma;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}
#moreButton{
    width:30px;
    font: bold 25px Tahoma;
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
    padding-left:5px;
}
#userID{
    width:120px;
    font: bold 25px Tahoma;
    padding-right:20px;
}
#top_header li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
#loginStuff{
    font: bold 12px Tahoma;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}


#new_div{
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}

#new_div2{
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    border-top:80px solid #F0F0F0;


}

#otherForms{
    background:white;
    width: 300px;
    border-top: 5px solid white;
    text-align:left;

}
#whiteSpace{
    background:white;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-radius:10px;
    bottom:0;
    width:900px;
    padding:20px;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;


}
#signupTitle{
    font: bold 18px Tahoma;
}
#theForms{

    padding-top:20px;

}
#textBox{
    float:right;
}
#submitButton{

    float:center;

}
#aligning{
    text-align:center;
}

#the_footer{
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    border-top:2px solid black;
}

.nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

    .nav ul li:hover  ul {
        display: block;
    }
    .nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }
.nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
        .nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

.nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    .nav ul ul li {
        position: relative;
    }
        .nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 0px 10px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            .nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4b545f;
            }
```